# Estimation is not reset when Bug is moved into Closed or Resolved status

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I noticed that by default a **Bug** can end up in 2 different states: **Closed** and **Resolved**
The issue is that when there is an estimation against it (**Remaining** field), this is not set to 0 when a Bug goes into one of these 2 states. 
While for the **Tasks**, when there is an estimation against it, if the Task is moved to the **Closed** status, that estimation is automatically set to 0.

I wanted to understand the "functional" reason behind it, and if there is any setting to enable this for the Bugs as well ?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If it is helpful to you ,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Sorry for the delay, I was busy with some development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue ,this is as designed. We clear the remaining hours for Tasks when the work item is Closed. However, bugs are slightly different because you have more flexibility with how you work with bugs and therefore we do not clear the remaining hours for the Bug work item type without a change to the process.

As a workaround, you can add a rule to the Bug work item type to clear Remaining Hours.
[image]

For details , you can refer to this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) and the [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/90633/remaining-of-bugs-is-not-cleared-on-close.html) with similar issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work around.
I'm kinda new to DevOps, do you have any good book or online material that I can follow in order to improve my abilities and understanding of DevOps in general ?
I mostly use Repos, Boards, Wiki and Pipelines.